# Eclipse crashes with Java 9 on Linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I'm on Debian Unstable (latest) amd64 with the GNOME desktop. Eclipse (which I installed using the [official installer](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)) crashes when run with the Java 9 VM with the following message:

```
An error has occurred. See the log file /home/furquan/Eclipse/.metadata/.log.
```

[This](https://pastebin.com/raw/ntyMfqxr) is the said log.

This problem is fixed when I specify the Java 8 VM but installing the Java 9 VM afterwards (after running Eclipse that is) leads to this error:

[image]

Rebuilding Java 8 projects with Java 9 VM shows the same error as above.

I'm using OpenJDK Java 9 JDK ([distro version](https://packages.debian.org/sid/openjdk-9-jdk)). This is my `eclipse.ini`:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
/home/furquan/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.550.v20170928-1359
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
```

Note that using Java 8 both as the VM for Eclipse and Java projects produces no such errors. I've reinstalled Eclipse multiple times and even deleted/changed workspaces but nothing seems to help. This is not a GTK error as `--launcher.GTK_version 2` is of no use.

Comment: Maybe this bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=493761

Comment: Please don't post errors as images. I know it's an ache to type, but images of code make your errors impossible to search, which makes your questions considerably less useful to future readers.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov So I should type out the errors exactly as in the images? The errors aren't exactly helpful (and there's a log) so I decided against it.

Comment: @hexman, the first one is bad, but the second one I think is fine.

Comment: @Patrick It's a different bug (and it's WONTFIX either way) because it concerns early-access builds of Java9 released in 2016. Java9 has already gone well past the release date. Besides, the workaround for the bug—`--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM`—won't work for me because it's already in my eclipse.ini by default.

Comment: Look for the eclipse version and its Java9 compatibility. I hope you don't have a conflicting plugin and latest oxygen installed(both for Java9) either. Saw that causing some issues as well.

Comment: @nullpointer It's a fresh install on a clean workspace and I've no plugins other than Eclipse for Java Developers.

Comment: @hexman And what about the compatibility?

Comment: @nullpointer It's the latest version of Eclipse (as I installed it using the official installer) and according to https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9 it should be compatible by default (and either way the solutions listed were already applied to my `eclipse.ini` by default when I installed it).